# Symfony on virtual host (document root problem)

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, symfony1, xampp, shared-hosting

I'm developing an application in Symfony and on localhost (XAMPP) I want to simulate the same conditions as on the webserver.

The web server is configured as follows:

```
/www   => mydomain.com
/foo   => foo.mydomain.com
/bar   => bar.mydomain.com
...
```

I'm going to put my Symfony application into `/www` direcotry so there'll be:

```
/www
/www/apps
/www/apps/frontend
/www/apps/frontend/...
/www/apps/backend
/www/apps/backend/...
/www/cache
/www/config
... and so on...
/www/web
```

The thing is that the document root is still set to the `/www` directory but Symfony expects it in the `/www/web`.
Of course it will work if I call `http://mydomain.com/web` but I guess you understand this is quiet stupid solution.

**So my question is**: Is there any way how can I change/bypass the default document root setting using .htaccess or whatever?

EDIT: [I solved it](http://www.martinsikora.com/symfony-1-4-on-shared-webhosting).

Comment: If you solved your own problem, answer your question and mark this question answered.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know much about Symfony but `/web` is supposed to be the document root. All the other directories should be outside the document root for security reasons for one, and to avoid the `/web` part in the URL for another. But it looks like you already know that.

If you can edit the web server's configuration, try to reflect that and set `DocumentRoot` to the web directory.

If you can't do that: It's not possible to change the `DocumentRoot` in a `.htaccess` file but it is possible to rewrite all requests so they go to `/web` internally using `mod_rewrite`. It's kludgy, but probably the best solution if you can't influence `DocumentRoot`.

I'm not a mod_rewrite guru so I can't provide an example (I would have to test it first and I can't do that right now) but I'm sure somebody will. Maybe add the `mod_rewrite` tag to your question.

**Update:** Untested but *should* work. Put into a `.htaccess` file in `/www`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/ 
RewriteRule .* /web/%1 [QSA]
```

you would then need to change your configuration files to use `http://www.domain.com/` instead of `http://www.domain.com/web/` of course.

I can't say whether that interferes with any other `.htaccess` rules on the Symfony end - you'd have to try out.

Answer (score 0):

I you got hand on apache config, the better is to move document root from `/www` to `/www/web` in you virtualHost config and allow php (if restricted by `open_basedir` configuration directive)  to access the whole `/www` directory.

Comment: That's exactly what I can't. I've never seen any shared webhosting where you can modify apache config :)

Comment: Ok what we have done once with a shared host is to remove the public web dir, put all sf project in the shared host root, then recreate the www dir with a symlink targeting to web/ directory, but dunno if you can add symlinks or not

Answer (score 0):

Change the way symfony expects your directory to be named :

```
// config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php
class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration
{
  public function setup()
  {
    $this->setWebDir($this->getRootDir().'/www/or/whatever/directory');
  }
}
```