# Use symfony 1.4 without changing apache configuration

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, symfony1, symfony-1.4

Is it possible to set the */web* directory as webroot without changing apache configuration file?

I tried using the following .htaccess code, but if i go to *localhost/module/*, it displays 404 error. But if i go to *localhost/web/module/* then everything works.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    sf/(.*) lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf/$1 [L]
   RewriteRule    ^$ web/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) web/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

i do like this on the root :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*) ./web/$1 [L]
```

And edit web/.htaccess uncommented the 'RewriteBase /' line.

this make all the mysite.com/aaaa/bbbb  works like mysite.com/web/aaaa/bbbb

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

Bit longer: you will have to edit the apache config at least to give it permission to access the web/ directory, so even if you symlink your web folder to /var/www, it will not work.

Comment: My web directory path is /home/xx/public_html/web

Comment: Then why not make /home/xx/public_html your webroot? Put your code in /home/xx, and edit your ProjectConfiguration to call `$this->setWebDir`? If it works, I'll update my answer.

Comment: i've put all my symfony files to /home/xx/private_html/ and left only /web folder contents to /home/xx/public_html/
But now i can't get it working. Symfony is still looking for its files from /home/xx/public_html/ folder.

Comment: Put these in your ProjectConfiguration class: `$this->setWebDir("/home/xx/public_html/"); $this->setRootDir("/home/xx/private_html/");`
I'm using something like this, but my symfony files are in /home/xx, and the webroot is /home/xx/public_html.

Comment: It still tryes to find its files from public_html

Answer (score 0):

This is quiet similar to my question [Symfony on virtual host (document root problem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809778/symfony-on-virtual-host-document-root-problem).

This is my `.htaccess` in the project root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /       

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/images/  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/js/      [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/css/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/index.php [QSA,L]
```

This solved my problem but symfony tries to generate every url (eg. using `url_for`) from the document root so instead of url like `domain.com/my-article` it generates `domain.com/web/my-article`.
I had to slightly modify my `PatternRouting` class to trim the `/web` prefix from each url. I think this is not the best solution but it works.

Also if I want to access backend application I have to call always `/web/backend.php/` because I don't want to have so many rewrite rules in the `.htaccess`.

If you want to see my extended `PatternRouting` class source code I'll paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Copy everything from web/ up a level to your document root. Edit index.php to reflect the fact that everything it includes is now one level closer to its current directory than it used to be (one less ../). You won't have to edit a single other Symfony file.