# symfony on virtual host document root problem

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

Im trying to [deploy symfony on virtual host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809778/symfony-on-virtual-host-document-root-problem).

mod_rewrite converts /web URLs to domain root URLs (domain.com/image.gif is turning internaly into domain.com/web/image.gif).

But thanks to web is executed internaly from /web dir, Symfony is still thinking it has document root there and prefixes any url_for() URLs with /web.

So when i have route:

```
show_books:
  url: /books
```

..and iam asking for:

```
url_for('@route_name')
```

Symfony is generating:

```
/web/books
```

**I cant change hosting behaviour, i need to have web request pointed into symfony root path and internaly redirected into /web dir and i want to symfony ignore the point it is executed from |hostname-document-root|/web**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the insert of this code into top of my front controller (/web/index.php) as good solution:

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = '/index.php';
```